# Como exibir SCROLL permanetimente ionic2

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Boa tarde,

Estou com um problema e gostaria da ajuda de vocês. Quero exibir o SCROLL sempre que estiver nessa tela, tentei de varias formas utilizar o componente ion-scroll e mesmo assim, nada. Tentei importa utilizando css overflow, mas também, não funcionou no celular.
Segue abaixo o content de uma tela que estou fazendo, para ter como exemplo.

```html
<ion-content >
  <ion-list >
    <ion-item-divider color="light">Dados de Solicitação de Compra</ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item>Data de Compra<p item-right>12/02/2017 14:00:00</p></ion-item>
    <ion-item>Data de Vencimento<p item-right>20/02/2017 18:00:00</p></ion-item>
    <ion-item>Setor<p item-right>Almoxarifado</p></ion-item>
    <ion-item>Solicitante<p item-right>Papai Noel</p></ion-item>
    <ion-item>Estoque<p item-right>20</p></ion-item>
    <ion-item>Motivo<p item-right>O Natal ta chegando</p></ion-item>
    <ion-item>Quantidade de itens<p item-right>15</p></ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-item-divider color="light">Lista de itens</ion-item-divider>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-list [virtualScroll]="solicitacao.itens" >
      <ion-item floating *virtualItem="let item">
          {{item.DS_PRODUTO}}<p>{{item.QT_SOLIC}} {{item.DS_UNIDADE}}</p>
      </ion-item>     
    </ion-list>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta mudar no CSS da página que pretende.

Tenta isto:

```
.ng-animate .scroll-bar {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.scroll-bar-fade-out{
  opacity:1 !important
}
```

Comment: João Tomás
Adicionei o código passado por você e mesmo assim, não aparece o scroll na tela de forma permanente. Deveria ter um atributo para mostrar ou esconder a barra de rolagem da tela. Já tentei fazer de varias formas, porém, nenhuma funciona.